# .htaccess/mod-rewrite affecting browser back button

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ articles.php?article=$1
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ articles.php?article=$1
```

This rewrites:

```
www.cristianrgreco.com/new/articles.php?article=search-engine-optimization
www.cristianrgreco.com/new/articles/search-engine-optimization
```

The file works fine, but if you do end up at the re-written link and press back on the browser, nothing happens. It literally just keeps loading forever and says 'waiting for cristianrgreco.com'

For a live example, go to: http://www.cristianrgreco.com/new/index.php and click 'read more' on any article, then press Back button on the browser.

Could someone help?

Comment: Going to your site, the back button works fine for me. Also you can combine those 2 rules to just this one: `RewriteRule ^articles/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ articles.php?article=$1`

Comment: It worked as expected in Firefox 6 and IE8.

Comment: This is working fine for me in Firefox, IE, Safari, and Chrome.

Comment: it's genuinely not working for me using latest version of Chrome, thank you Jon I have used your code instead. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: working fine for me on ie, safari and firefox, not on chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It work's fine for me on IE9, FF and Chrome as well. I think you can assume this has nothing to do with your site. If you're using Chrome BETA, you can probably expect this kind of bugs: its beta.

Comment: It's not a beta but is working now too. V sorry for false alarm it seems to be working now. Very odd. Thanks for everyone's help!